# Is there any rest API available to convert HTML to PDF file public link

Tags: html, google-app-engine, pdf

Is there a web service for converting HTML/JSON to PDF links?

We want to generate PDF file from google app engine . Since app engine doesn't have any file system it is not possible to create a file . So only possible way to generate the PDF links like the public link in cloud storage . Is there any Application giving the storage of files ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this via javascript with `html2pdf` https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf. App engine then served 'pdf ready' html to my javascript which passed it through to `html2pdf`.

Option 2 would be to setup an App Engine Flex micro-service specifically for tasks like this that need a file system.